# Docker is looking for another postgres reference

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to add `postgres` to my docker compose file, but every time I execute `docker-compose up`, I look for another reference of the image, and is not running properly.

**Dockfile**

```
FROM node:12.13-alpine As development

WORKDIR /app
ADD package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
RUN npm install

ADD . /app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

**docker-componse.yml**

```
version: '2.0'
services:
    db:
        image: "postgres:12"
        networks:
            - webnet
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_DB: demo
    web:
        image: postgres-docker-image
        ports: 
            - "5432:5432"
        networks: 
            - webnet
        environment: 
            DB_HOST: db
networks: 
    webnet:
```

And if I execute the command: `docker-compose up` I get:

> Pulling db (postgres:12)... 12: Pulling from library/postgres Digest:
> sha256:6a250876f8dec6fcf1f3ce255da7c02cb74c48bab023e073fd4f3125d496a275
> Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:12 Pulling web
> (postgres-docker-image:)... ERROR: The image for the service you're
> trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data
> could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.

Continue with the new image? [yN]y

```
Pulling web (postgres-docker-image:)...
ERROR: pull access denied for postgres-docker-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

But if I execute the command: `docker images` I get:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              28306fe7bfce        2 hours ago         598MB
<none>              <none>              15fafa0e9ae8        2 hours ago         592MB
postgres            12                  4b52913b0a3a        4 days ago          313MB
postgres            latest              4b52913b0a3a        4 days ago          313MB
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: The `db` container on `postgres:12` is working fine. The problem is your `web` container that's created from some `postgres-docker-image`, which doesn't exist. Did you mean to specify your custom dockerfile for that container?

Comment: I'm trying to pull the image from docker hub.

Comment: There is no [`postgres-docker-image`](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres-docker-image) on docker hub.

Comment: you right! but in my docker and docker compose file, there doesn't exist any reference to postgres-docker-image

Comment: There does, at least in the compose file you posted in your question: `web:
        image: postgres-docker-image`

Comment: You're completely right!